# How to use an embed in a Postmaster parcel

Tags: postmaster

Whenever I use an embed in my EE Postmaster parcel the only content that is displayed is the content generated by the embed. My entire template is wiped out and replaced with just the value that is returned from my embed. According to ObjectiveHTML embeds are supported so I'm hoping there is some way I can get my embed working and not breaking the rest of my template. Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my Postmaster parcel below:

{exp:channel:entries channel="gear_orders" limit="1" dynamic="no"}

Gear Invoice

Order Data






Order Date:  
{entry_date format="%l - %F %j, %Y"}







  Order ID:  
Gear Order #{entry_id}

---

Ordered By
{member_firstname} {member_lastname}


Email
   
  {gear_ordered_by_email}



Billing
   
Employee



Shipping
{gear_ship_to}

Items Ordered
      {member_firstname} {member_lastname}
     
     
    Total
      {gear_order}

{gear_quantity} - {gear_item}   {embed="embed/.geartotal" gear_product="{gear_item}" gear_quantity="{gear_quantity}"}

{/gear_order}

{/exp:channel:entries}

Here is the content of my .geartotal embed:

{exp:channel:entries channel="gear_products" dynamic="no" search:title="{embed:gear_product}" limit="1"}
            {exp:multiply numbers="{embed:gear_quantity}|{gear_price}"}
{/exp:channel:entries}

This is running on ExpressionEngine 2.5.2 with Postmaster 1.4.3

Comment: Hi James, can we see some code and EE version?

Comment: No problem sorry, just updated the post with the code from my postmaster parcel and the embed it's trying to use plust the EE version and Postmaster version. Let me know if you need anything else thanks!

Comment: Looks like you are experiencing a parsing order issue, James. Can you change the embeds to snippets?

Comment: Did you figure this out, Andrew?

Comment: No never did figure this out. Changing to a snippet did not work either.